# Linux: Execute script every day at midnight and remove all files in folder except latest 20

Tags: linux

How can I run some kind of script on linux ubuntu server once a day at midnight to basically remove all images in public/images/uploads/ except last 20?
So say during day 59 images were uploaded, it would remove 1-38 and leave last 20 (39-59) there.

I am new to linux so I am unfamiliar with all such things.

Comment: Read about cron and find.

Comment: Create one script in any language you're comfortable and then call it using cron. To avoid your question to be closed (and allow people to help you) post some code you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Place this script in cron to start at midnight.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ${SOMEDIR}/public/images/uploads/ 
cnt=$(ls | wc -l) # number of files
cnt=${cnt}-20     # subtract 20
if [ ${cnt} -gt 0 ] # Check if there are files to delete
then
    ls -t | tail --lines=${cnt} | while read file
    do
        rm $file # delete all but first 20.
    done
fi
```

Comment: Where do I specify which folder to delete files from?

Comment: Add a cd at top of script.